# Deriving from a CGAL class compatible with CGAL::assign

Tags: c++, object, derived-class, assign, cgal

I want to derive from the CGAL::Parabola_segment_2 class. Because I would like to access two
protected data members which can not be accessible through public member functions.

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Segment_Delaunay_graph_traits_without_intersections_2< Kernel,
    CGAL::Integral_domain_without_division_tag> Gt;
typedef CGAL::Segment_Delaunay_graph_2<Gt> SDG_2;
typedef SDG_2::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
typedef SDG_2::Finite_edges_iterator Finite_edges_iterator;
typedef Gt::Line_2 Line_2;
typedef Gt::Ray_2 Ray_2;
typedef Gt::Segment_2 Segment_2;
typedef Gt::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef Gt::Site_2 Site_2;

class Parabola_segment_2 : public CGAL::Parabola_segment_2<Gt> { };
```

My code compiles and runs but the if statement in the code given below never returns true. But I'm sure it must return true for some values.

```
.......
CGAL::Object o = sdg.primal(*eit);
Segment_2 s;
Parabola_segment_2 ps;
if(CGAL::assign(s, o)) {
...
}
```

If I change

```
class Parabola_segment_2 : public CGAL::Parabola_segment_2<Gt> { };
```

with

```
typedef CGAL::Parabola_segment_2<Gt> Parabola_segmet_2;
```

then the program executes exactly as I want, but I couldn't access the variables that I wanted. My question is how should I derive the CGAL class such that it is compatible with the CGAL::assign() function?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use template deduction, and explicit the type expected. That is:

```cpp
if( CGAL::assign<CGAL::Parabola_segment_2<Gt> >(ps, o)) {
...
}
```